# Right way to make embedded forms

Tags: django, django-forms

What is the right way to make embedded form with manyToMany, oneToMany, etc? I would like to build form rendering like django auto-generated admin ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)).

Answer (score 0):

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/ for examples of how to render one or more forms for models that are associated to other models.